# How to prevent that a event in a control trigger when the form is closing

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

My problem is that I validate a `TextBox` in the `Leave` event and I check that this `TextBox` has something. If the text in this `TextBox` is the same to zero a `MessageBox` appears, but if the form is closing and the focus is in this `TextBox` the `MessageBox` appears because the `TextBox` doesn't have anything.

How can avoid the validate in the `Leave` event when the form is closing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to override the [`OnFormClosing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onformclosing.aspx) method on the form and set a flag letting you know that the form is closing. Then, when validating, check that flag first.

Be sure to set the flag ***before*** calling `base`.

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    _isClosing = true;

    base.OnFormClosing(e);
}
```

Comment: i wanna try this, but how i assign this event that override, _isClosing is the flat that i need validating?

Comment: @JoséGordilloLópez, please see my update (I changed `virtual` to `override`). Further, `_isClosing` is the class variable `private bool _isClosing;` that you'll set to let the form know it's closing. Then in the `Leave` event you'll do this, `if (_isClosing) { return; }` to cancel the validation.

Comment: thanks, this work very well, and for the rest of user, thanks

Comment: You can avoid this by using the validate event instead of the leave event to do the validation.

Answer (score 4):

One way would be to remove the events the textbox raises. I'm not sure how you're validating but you could try setting the `Enabled` property to false in the `FormClosing` event.

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(Object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) 
{        
    myTextBox.Enabled = false; 
}
```

Or remove the `Leave` event handler

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(Object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) 
{       
    myTextBox.Leave -= myTextBox_Leave;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the textbox's "validated" event to achieve this instead of the "leave" event.

This will ensure your code is executed before the form closes and should achieve precisely what you need.